# Can I access a member variable of a child class through a reference to a parent class?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a program that needs to test the value of a boolean variable (isBasic) located in the child of a class. e.g:

```
class Card{
     //some stuff here
 }

class land extends Card{
    private boolean isBasic;
    public void isBasic(){
        return isBasic;
    }
}

class usesCards extends somethingElse{
    //initialize variables like SIZE
    Card cardList = new Card[SIZE];

    public void addCard(Card card){
        if (card.isBasic()){
            //the rest
        }
    }
}
```

It keeps telling me that the method isBasic() doesn't exist in Card. I don't think it should exist in Card because it is a specific part of Land. Card's other children should not have that variable. Do I need to put it in card and then use only the important variables for each child or can I initialize isBasic in Land and leave it out of Card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a method of derived class in object of the base class if it's not instance of it. You have to perform a class check against the `card` object first. You can only use `isBasic` method if your `Card` object is a `Land` at the same time, and you'll have to perform [object casting](https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/java-cast/).

I let myself change class names to PascalCase, because [this is a recommended naming convention in Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java).

```
class Card {
     //some stuff here
}

class Land extends Card {
    private boolean isBasic;
    public void isBasic(){
        return isBasic;
    }
}

class UsesCards extends SomethingElse {
    //initialize variables like SIZE
    Card cardList = new Card[SIZE];

    public void addCard(Card card){
        // Checking card's actual class.
        if (card instanceof Land && ((Land)card).isBasic()){
            //the rest
        }
    }
}
```

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) you can read more about inheritance in Java.

Comment: Thank you so much! that was exactly what i was needing. I had forgotten about the keyword "instanceof"